# Is it correct to use The word taste for movie

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

Is it correct to say this movie is not according to my taste.
Could one use taste in this respect. Is there any other appropriate word?

Comment: [**taste**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/taste), 5: *Personal preference; liking; predilection.* Why should this be incorrect?

Comment: Gotcha. I just looked at the dictionary and seems there are lot of ways this could be used. That's interesting! Is there some article that explains how or why a single word started having different meanings when used in different contexts